# Route subdomains to specific physical folders IIS

Tags: iis, web-config

I need to migrate my Linux + Apache application to a Windows + IIS server. In my Apache .htaccess I have the following configuration, which was mapping various subdomains to different physical directories:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

# BACKOFFICE API
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^(?:api\.mysite\.com)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*) public/$1 [NC,L,NS]

# FRONTEND API
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^(?:src\.mysite\.com)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*) public/$1 [NC,L,NS]

# ANYOTHER TO DIST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dist
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dist/$1 [L] ...
```

The point is that I need this same behavior in IIS, I suppose by configuring these same rules for IIS in a web.config file.
As can be deduced from the .htaccess rules, I have two working directories in my application:
/wwwroot/dist,
/wwwroot/public.
I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Creating Rewrite Rules for URL Rewrite Module in IIS can help you achieve your requirements, refer this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module. 
I see your next question already created rewrite rules, post and accept your own answer and then you can close the discussion.

Comment: I created a rule set but the problem is not solved, my front-end app is not working yet. So I think the question should be left open.

Comment: Use FRT to reveal what are the things inside incoming requests that you can utilize to write your rules, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules